# One table view , one section , tree custom cell ( Possible duplicate )

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

Possible duplicate : [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107157/how-to-use-different-cell-in-one-table-view)

I have 3 custom cell with Xib ( customCell1, customCell2, customCell3 ) and i need to set all of them only in one section ( i have don it before with 3 section without any problem ) .

customCell**1** : is a static cell (an image)

customCell**3** : is also a  static cell (UITextView with a button)

customCell**2** : must be dynamic (Its contain a MutableArray) which is may have different value in different situation...

My questions are : 1 : in consider to cell number two which have different rows how can i return :
 `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`
my first Row must be (customCell**1**) and my last row must be (customCell**3** ) in rows between must be (customCell**2**) ?

2 : in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` how can i separate this custom cells and call them in their own indexPath ?

Answer (score 0):

If your first cell has to always be customCell1 and your last has to always be customCell3, which are both static and you only need 1 section, why not just using a tableView Header and Footer?

Example of checking IndexPath.row:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if(indexPath.row == 0){

        FirstCell *firstCell = (FirstCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:"TopCell"];

        //do your changes to the cell here

        return firstCell;

    }else if(indexPath.row == dataArray.count-1){

        LastCell *lastCell = (LastCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:"LastCell"];

        //do your changes to the cell here

        return lastCell;

    }

    NormalCell *normalCell = (NormalCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:"normalCell"];

    //do your changes to the cell here
    //For example
    cell.titleLabel.text = dataArray[indexPath.row].valueForKey("title"); 

    return normalCell;

}
```

Comment: I know there are many ways to do it but my boss create this challenge , and he wants all of this tree be in one section without nay header and footer ... as i mentioned have done it before with 3sections.

Comment: then you could check the indexPath.row i guess, if it's 0 then it's the first cell, if it's = dataArray.count-1 then its the last one, i'll update the answer to show you a code example